# What steps are required to transfer real estate into a LLC?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, limited-liability-company, landlord

I'm a fairly new landlord, and learning as I go. Apparently one of the early mistakes I made when purchasing my rental properties was buying them under my name instead of forming a Limited Liability Corporation to own them.

So I'm trying to fix that, but I'm concerned about what hoops I will likely have to jump through to transfer ownership of the properties to the LLC, especially considering it has a mortgage on it (technically a home equity loan on my primary residence).

Obviously I'll hire an attorney or financial adviser before actually setting this up, but I was hoping the financial gurus here on PF&M might give me a preview of what to expect. Is this a complicated transaction? Any gotchas I should be aware of before embarking on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> especially considering it has a mortgage on it (technically a home
>   equity loan on my primary residence).

I'm not following. Does it have a mortgage on it, or your primary residence (a different property) was used as a security for the loan? If it is HELOC from a different property - then it is really your business what to do with it. You can spend it all on casinos in Vegas for all that the bank cares.

> Is this a complicated transaction? Any gotchas I should be aware of
>   before embarking on it?

Obviously you should talk to an attorney and a tax adviser. But here's my two cents:

1. State - your LLC will be doing business in the State where the property is located, and in the State where you live. If this is not the same State - you'll have to register it in both (either as domestic or foreign). Unless you are planning on moving a lot and buying properties in different states - I suggest to set up the LLC in one of these two States, and it doesn't usually matter which one. But do check where being domestic is cheaper than being foreign - that would be the best criteria.

Don't fall for the "incorporate in Nevada/Delaware/Wyoming/Some other lie" trap. You *must* register in the State where you live, and in the State where the property is. Incorporating in any other State will just *add* complexity and costs, and will not save you *anything* whatsoever.

2.1 State Taxes - some States tax LLCs. For example, in California you'll pay at least $800 a year just for the right of doing business. If you live in California or the property is in California - you *will* pay this if you decide to set up an LLC.

2.2 Income taxes - make sure to **not** elect to tax your LLC as a corporation. The default for LLC is "disregarded" status and it will be taxed for income tax purposes as your person. I.e.: IRS doesn't care and doesn't know about it (and most States, as well). If you actively select to tax it as a corporation (there's such an option) - it will cost you very dearly. So don't, and if someone suggest such a thing to you - run away from that person as fast as you can.

3. Mortgages - it is very hard to get a mortgage when the property is under the LLC. If you already have a mortgage on that property (the property is the one securing the loan) - it may get called once you transfer it into LLC, since from bank's perspective that would be transferring ownership.
4. Local taxes - transferring into LLC may trigger a new tax assessment. If you just bought the property - that will probably not matter much. If it appreciated - you may get hit with higher property taxes.

There are also many little things - once you're a LLC and not individual you'll have to open a business bank account, will probably need a new insurance policy, etc etc. These don't add much to costs and are more of an occasional nuisance.

Comment: Great feedback, thanks. To clarify the point you asked about. It was financed with a second mortgage on my primary home. Also, this is all within the same county/state.