# I just bought a home and I want my new address to not be searchable by using my name. How can I keep my new address from being found

Tags: real-estate, first-time-home-buyer, home-ownership, security, privacy

I understand that all real estate transactions are public knowledge. As far as displaying the value of my new home, how much it was purchased for, or if we took out a load or bought it in cash, I can understand why the real estate market would need that info for buyers' and sellers' protection. However, how can I make sure that my new address is not easily searchable if someone just typed my full name and the city I live in into Google Search or something like that? Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

I just don't want possible psychopaths to be able to find my name, and then easily find where my family and I live. Like I said I don't care about the land info and purchase price. I just don't want my name associated with it publicly.

I already removed myself from the Whitepages' and some other "find people" websites. I just don't think that excludes these home purchases.

Does anyone have any advice?

I know I can open an LLC and put the purchase of the home under the LLC to protect my name but we are too far into this home purchase right now. Is there any other solution?

edit:
I purchased my place in Chicago, Illinois. Anyone know the rules and regulations for Chicago?

Comment: You have your own answer.  If it is post-closing is there a reason you can't transfer your house to your LLC now (other than process and fees for redoing the mortgage if you have one)?  If pre-closing why, as the buyer, you can't control the timeline and details of the closing in order to have the sale reflect your LLC as the owner?

Comment: what jurisdiction are you in? Please [edit] accordingly as different jurisdictions may have differing rules about anonymity.

Comment: If you've already closed, it's too late to do anything much about this.

Comment: @user662852 - not clear that a mortgage company would want to redo the loan to change to an LLC. Should have bought as an LLC in the first place. Many places in the US now have complete real estate info online in a GIS system.

Comment: Yeah we already set a closing date which in a couple weeks. As for the GIS system, will they be able to pull my address by typing my name in there?

Comment: LLC doesn't help much, can search LLC owner just as easily.

Comment: Also see: [What are the financial ramifications for buying a house under my LLC](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/139180/14319) and [What steps are required to transfer real estate into a LLC?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/39921/14319)

Comment: @HartCO Not necessarily. Last I checked, there were a couple of U.S. states that don't require a known owner for LLCs, only a registered agent or similar. Also, unless it's as easy as an internet search, added friction to dig out each piece of information improves privacy. A land trust, rather than an LLC, in an alternate trust name is one of the traditional ways to separate your personal name from the ownership of the land.